# While installing Ubuntu 12.04, "An error has occurred setting the element data"

Tags: system-installation

I come from a region with very slow internet speed. This makes installing Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 inside Windows 7 home a painfully slow/difficult process. Today, it is finally complete after trying for two weeks. Sadly, after extracting, the following error is shown:

```
>>stdout=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 697, in modify_bcd
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set {69ddb1fb-def5-11e2-b1b1-fa7722f9a0cd} device partition=H:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.

The request is not supported.
```

and then the window closed. I ran Wubi again, but it asked to uninstall the previous of Ubuntu. If I do that, then do I need to start the download process all over again?

Is there any other option?

I need Windows 7 too.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause - Disk being 'Dynamic'.
Open Disk Management in windows 7 and check the 'Type' of each Partition.
if it shows 'Dynamic' then you cannot install ubuntu or any other distro. you need to change it to 'Basic' type which requires deletion of all partitions.
Better install it on a external hd or pendrive.